# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setHttpOnly(Z)V

Tags: java, gradle, weblogic-10.x

I am using weblogic 10.3.6.0 application server for deploying application . after
deploying one of the application which uses JDK8. at run time I got the following error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setHttpOnly(Z)V

contents of **dependencies.gradle** file are as follows

> providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

What would be the reason behind this error?

Comment: might be version issue with servlets.jar

Comment: How to know which servlet jar my weblogic is using?

Comment: If your weblogic is v10.0, servlet version would is 2.5. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server for more details

Comment: If you need specifically servlet 3.0.1 you might require WLS 12cR1

Comment: Yes and setHttpOnly method not available in Cookie class of servlet-2.5 jar

Comment: Yes Pawan. Below answer by @Karol Dowbecki clearly explains the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Cookie.setHttpOnly()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setHttpOnly(boolean)) is available since Servlet 3.0. You are deploying to WebLogic 10 which provides only Servlet 2.5.

Note that your project is compiling against an API dependency and not the actual runtime implementation. This is correct project setup, don't change it. However you must ensure that the APIs that you selected for compilation are provided in the runtime by deploying to the correct server.

Comment: Correct server means I have to upgrade to weblogic 12+ verion right?

Comment: @PawanPatil yes, or ditch WebLogic for some other servlet container that uses API 3.0

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you are compiling against the wrong servlet jar for your version of weblogic. If you want to keep using weblogic 10 then you should change to

```
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:2.5'
```

Once you do this I'm guessing you'll get a compilation error for `Cookie.setHttpOnly()`.

Out of interest, why are you using weblogic? There's many free / open source servlet containers that are far better than weblogic. Weblogic doesn't conform to the same standards as the rest of the servlet containers.

Comment: Choosing Weblogic over other servlet containers is my company decision.

Comment: The guy who created weblogic says its his biggest mistake! https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-11944966

Comment: He had mentioned about Websphere which is IBM product and WebLogic is Oracle product kindly read that news again.

Comment: Ah, I'm getting the two confused. I've only had (negative) experience with Websphere. Have never touched weblogic

Comment: Generally WebLogic is preferred because of enterprise level support available from Oracle.  JBoss is also good one from Redhat for enterprise level support. for open source Glassfish is preferred because it is oldest and loads of documentation available over internet. I absolutely don't have any Idea regarding WebSphere.